# onConfigurationChanged() not called on orientation change

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I have an `Activity` that displays just an image. I want the image to rotate when I rotate my phone. I have read nearly all of SO posts on orientation changes and this is what I did:

**AlternateFullImageActivity.java**

```
public class AlternateFullImageActivity extends me.imid.swipebacklayout.lib.app.SwipeBackActivity {

    String API;
    String photoId;
    String token;
    TinyDB tinyDB;
    RestAdapter restAdapter;
    @Bind(R.id.zoomable)
    ImageView image;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
    Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alternate_full_image);
        SwipeBackLayout mSwipeBackLayout = getSwipeBackLayout();
        mSwipeBackLayout.setEdgeTrackingEnabled(SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_ALL);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Log.i("PP", "AlternateFullImageActivity called");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        photoId = intent.getExtras().getString("ID");

        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
            }
        };
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(API)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();

        PhotoAPI photoAPI = restAdapter.create(PhotoAPI.class);
        photoAPI.getFeed(photoId, new Callback<ImageItem>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ImageItem imageItem, Response response) {
                Picasso.with(AlternateFullImageActivity.this)
                        .load(imageItem.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                bmp = bitmap;
                                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                            }
                        });
                mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(image);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.i("PP", "onConfigurationChanged called");
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
```

**activity_alternate_full_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.galleri5.android.activities.AlternateFullImageActivity">

    <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/zoomable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.galleri5.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="com.galleri5.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.galleri5.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LaunchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FullImageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AlternateFullImageActivity"
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|uiMode|screenSize|orientation">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

The problem is that `onConfigurationChanged()` is not being called at all even on rotating the phone. To check where the problem was, I created a new project with just one activity displaying an image and adding same config flags in manifest file and it works there. I can't figure out what the problem is and how to solve it.

**Edit**

I noticed another thing, when I add `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` for my activity in the manifest file, then the image rotates on rotating the phone, but `onCreate()` as well as `onConfigurationChanged()` is being called every time I rotate the phone. Now suppose this activity is denoted by C, then at this instant the activity back-stack is A-B-C. And every time I rotate the phone, the `onCreate` of A is also getting called, which is very weird to absorb for me. I am really out of ideas here. I definitely do not want `onCreate` of any activity to be called again. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you ,I would have taken following approach. ( I have not tested this code but It should give you pointer on how to proceed )

If you implement following approach then you don't need to worry about adding configChanges and manually handing orientation changes. Also Using onConfigurationChanged is not recommended much.

Use `onSaveInstanceState` to retain url across activity recreation and use onCreate as following.

```
private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
private String mUrl = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_URL) != null) {
  mUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_URL);
  loadImage(mUrl);
 } else {
  fetchNetworkUrl();
 }
}

private void fetchNetworkUrl() {
        // Service call and call following when you receive the url.

        photoAPI.getFeed(photoId, new Callback<ImageItem>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ImageItem imageItem, Response response) {
                mUrl = imageItem.getPhotoUrl();
                loadImage(mUrl);
            }
        }
    }

private void loadImage(String url){
        // Use Picasso to load Image
}
```

to Retain url across activity recreation use following

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
 outState.putString(KEY_URL, mUrl);
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat approach. But if I don't add any config lines in manifest, the screen does not rotate. Adding config line in a new project that I created to try work fine but adding the config line in my current project just does not rotate the screen. Screen rotation only works when I add screenOrientation=sensor. Please see the edit. I would really use your approach but the problem is screen does not rotate. How to trigger that?